# Toshiba Satellite Pro L300 1AI with Vista

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, backup, freeze, hard-drive-failure

I have an old Toshiba Satellite Pro L300 1AI laptop which has been getting slow to boot over time. Issue has occured where after a 10 minute startup into Vista, it freezes (including action bar clock). Cannot click/hotkey/open anything even after leaving for an hour.

Suspcicion is a failing hard drive, which is fine, but can I extract all the harddrive data like pictures and videos onto either another laptop or external HD if I can't use any functions? Can this be done in "safe mode" or something similar?

Any assistance much appreciated.
Many thanks
Russell

Answer (score 0):

`Hirens boot CD` is a great tool for this type of scenario.

http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Use `HDTune 2.55` to check the status of your hard drive.

There may not be anything wrong with your hard drive, just may be running really slow. If the tests come back fine consider doing a cleanup on your PC using tools such as `CCleaner` (http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)

As for the data transfer, use either safemode or any boot cd to access the files then plug in your external HD and transfer any thing you need or want to keep. Use this as a last resort though, check the other 2 ways I mentioned first.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and informative response Ash. I will try the boot CD first.